# getTitle of current url unit test using protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

try to check current url and get title of html page. 
i create test to click my account button and since user did not log in before , then website redirect to login page and then i used sendKeys to send user name and password then click login button but after calling browser.getCurrentUrl()
and browser.getTitle() still return same title as before logging in.

```
    beforeEach(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('https://*******************.net/');
});T

it(' childern (li) of parent (ul) with class(nav)  should have names Login/Register/Forgot Password/Forgot Username', function () {
    var myAccount = element(by.id('navItem_MyAccount'));
    myAccount.click();
    list = element.all(by.css('#tabs-Login li'));    
    expect(list.get(0).getText()).toBe('Login');
    expect(list.get(1).getText()).toBe('Register');
    expect(list.get(2).getText()).toBe('Forgot Password');
    expect(list.get(3).getText()).toBe('Forgot Username');

}, 10000);

it(' logIn should be active', function () {
    var myAccount = element(by.id('navItem_MyAccount'));
    myAccount.click();
    _login = element.all(by.css('.active'));
    expect(list.get(0).getText()).toBe('Login');

}, 1000);

it(' Page Title should be iSportsman: Home ', function () {
    var _login = element.all(by.css('#Login'));
    var log = element.all(by.css('#btnLogin'));
    var _loginPw = element.all(by.css('#inputRow-Password'));
    _login.sendKeys('************************');
    console.log('step1 done');

    _loginPw.sendKeys('*********');
    console.log('step2 done');

    log.click();
    console.log('step3 done');
    var _url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    console.log(_url.toString());
    browser.get(_url.toString());

    browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
        expect(title).toEqual('imakerman: Home');
    })

},10000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

it found answer i forget to click my account button before sendKeys for password and user_name in third test. then i combine user_name and password in one promise and then i clicked login button

```
it(' Page Title should be iMaker: Home ', function () {
    var myAccount = element(by.id('navItem_MyAccount'));
    myAccount.click();
    var log = element.all(by.css('#btnLogin'));
    var _login = element.all(by.css('#Login')).sendKeys('*****************');

    console.log('step1 done');

    var _loginPw = element.all(by.css('#Password')).sendKeys('**********');

    console.log('step2 done');

    protractor.promise.all([_login, _loginPw]).then(function () {

     log.click();
    });
    console.log('step3 done');
    browser.getCurrentUrl();

    browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
        expect(title).toEqual('iMaker: Home');
    })

 },5000);
 });
```